# javascript program not appending markup correctly

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am following a tutorial in Jasmine and serverless. The problem I am facing is around Javascript.

There is a public directory which has an index.html
Jasmine tests are in public/tests directory. It also has an index.html.

Following JS code (SpecHelper.js below) is suppose to find markups with class `markup` in public/index.html and copy that code in `<body>` of public/tests/index.html but it isn't doing so. I am unable to find the issue.

public/index.html

```
  <body>
      <div class='markup'>
        <div class='view-container container'>
            <div class='one-half column'>
                <h3>Learn JS, one puzzle at a time</h3>
                <a href='' class='button button-primary'>Start now!</a>         
            </div>
            <div class='one-half column'>
                <img src='/images/HeroImage.jpg'/>
            </div>
        </div>
       </div>
  </body>
```

SpecHelper.js

```
var fixture;

function loadFixture(path) {  
  var html;
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/index.html',
    success: function(result) {
      html = result;
    },
    async: false
  });          
  return $.parseHTML(html);
}

function resetFixture() {
  if (!fixture) {
    var index = $('<div>').append(loadFixture('/index.html'));
    var markup = index.find('div.markup');
    fixture = $('<div class="fixture" style="display: none">').append(markup);
    $('body').append(fixture.clone());
  } else {
    $('.fixture').replaceWith(fixture.clone());
  }
}

beforeEach(function () {
  resetFixture();
});
```

public/tests/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.3.4</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine_favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.css">

  <!-- App Dependencies -->
  <script src="lib/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script src="/vendor.js"></script>

  <!-- Test libraries -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.3.4/boot.js"></script>

  <!-- include source files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script>

  <!-- include spec files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="SpecHelper.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app_spec.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!--This is always empty! -->
  </body>
</html>
```

The test in Jasmine fails with following error

```
1 spec, 1 failure
Spec List | Failures
learnJS can show problem view
Expected 0 to equal 1.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it working..phew ... had to clear browser cache by going to developer tools, networks. I noticed that most files were being picked from memory. Right clicked and cleared cache and cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
fixture = $('<div class="fixture" style="display: none">').append(markup.html());
```

Then maybe

```
$('body').append(fixture.clone().html());
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't work. It is strange but the original code works if I use live-server instead of simple-server!! Could you think of some reason? One difference is that I am running simple-server from bash on windows and live-server from cmd in windows.